# CSS Selector not working as expected when SVG present

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

I have this JS Fiddle that works well, making my custom title display on mouseover and hide on mouseout. <strike>The problem I am having when transporting it to real world environment is that the ~ tilde selector doesn't work anymore. Is there another way to do this? My .message div is at very end of page ( as I had to close SVG tags first ), so I know the + plus selector won't work.</strike>

I realized that the real problem on my webpage as opposed to the fiddle is that my button class items are svg elements and while the tilde targeting works properly if the two elements are non svg, it doesn't work properly if one element is svg and the other isn't.

I added an svg element of the same class "button" to the Fiddle to demonstrate this issue.
If anyone can show me how to properly target this, I will be most grateful.

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrEbe/)

```
.button:hover ~ .message {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: "the selector doesn't work anymore" what do you mean by that? It works otherwise.

Comment: It works fine on fiddle but if I copy and paste to my webpage it doesn't work.

Comment: The CSS isn't the problem, its the JS. Do you have jQuery on the website? Pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: `~` will only work on siblings. You are probably aware of that. So the answer is no, unless you can put these elements beside each other, there isn't a solution in pure CSS, you would need additional JS

Comment: The limitations are as referenced in the specs for CSS. `p~ul -> Selects every <ul> element that are preceded by a <p> element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Is there a reason you can't just apply `class="button"` to the SVG?  It seems to achieve what you are after.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrEbe/8/)

**Update**

Instead of trying to achieve the message show with pure CSS, just use a little extra jQuery.  Add a class to the message element when you mouseover "button".

```
$('.message').addClass("visible-message");
```

Then remove it again when you mouseout.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrEbe/10/)

Comment: No. That is unacceptable, as not every element in my svg is a button as it is in the Fiddle.

Comment: I find it interesting that that even worked at all. Is there a way to select child perhaps that would work as well? Something like: svg>rect[class="button"]:hover ~ .message

Comment: This selector kind of works, but it is still not right. It is not specifically targeting the class! svg:nth-child(n):hover ~ .message You can see it in my updated fiddle in Original Post.

Comment: I already had a javascript version working, but it wasn't as elegant as yours. It would sometimes leave the title displayed if I moused over and out too quickly. Your version incorporates CSS as well, and while I wanted a pure CSS answer, to avoid the problem I was having, your answer did eliminate that problem. I see SVG has some serious shortcomings still as it doesn't play well with others. I will accept this updated answer and award you the bounty. Thank you sir for sticking with it.

Comment: This is not SVG's fault. You would have the same problem if, say, one of the button divs was inside another div.